# what would be the best way to copy table from server A to server B in sql 2012?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, replication

I have table A that is on server 1 and table B that is on server 2. 
Table contain around 1.5 million rows. 
What would be the fastest way to copy table A to server B? On nightly basis.

Or what would be the fastest way to bring only records that changed in table A and bring it to table B?

So far I tried `MERGE` along with `HASHBYTES` function to only capture records that changed. It works perfectly if target and source tables are on the same server. (takes approx 1 min).

But if target is on server B but the source is on server A - than it takes more than 15 min.

What is on your opinion the best and fastest technique for such operations?

Some sorts of replications? Or maybe SSIS would be the best for that?

Comment: Create the table on the target server then use `INSERT INTO`

Comment: I did. takes the same as using `MERGE`, which is approx 12 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents. Since you qualified your question with "On nightly basis", I'd say do this in SSIS.

Comment: So SSIS would be the fastest way? Is that what you saying?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the fastest way considering that you are going to do this on "On nightly basis". Set it once and forget it (develop once and schedule to run every night).

Answer (score 0):

I would use SSIS, it is designed to do fast large data copies between servers.

Also, if you can drop table B then you could try using SELECT INTO rather than INSERT INTO.

SELECT INTO is much faster as it is minimally logged but note that table B will be locked while the insert is running.

You could also try disabling indexes on Table B before you insert and re enabling them later.